# Woocommerce Different Products Different Currency

Tags: woocommerce, product, currency, rates

Can i define **different currencies** for products?

For example: X product is USD, Y product is RUB

Comment: Solved: I'm using product woocommerce product default currency plugin

Comment: could you link to the plugin's webpage?

Comment: Yo can look the [link](http://codeaffairs.com/product-default-currency/) .if you want they send you a demo.